# how to send return address backwards (through socket)- python

Tags: python, sockets, remote-access, buffer-overflow, endianness

I'm here to ask for a remote bufferoverflow tip. I'm currently solving a wargame and it's my first time trying these some new types of coding.

Currently I am trying to make a code like this:

Pretend I have an address variable which has a range of 0xbfffff00 and 0xbfffffff. I want to brute-force this return address, which I'll socket.send through some socket programming. The problem is, the os I am using to learn from is in little-endian format, so I would like to send my return address backwards(by byte).

Example) addr = 0xb1234567
 #I'd want to send 674523b1.

I've searched for a function like that and I found that print ('something'[::-1]).encode("hex") does the work, but this seems to work on strings, not when it is the number itself. Is there a way in python to send the address backwards?

Thanks.

Comment: The function `htonl()` will convert 32-bits little-endian to big-endian as long as the system is in little-endian architecture.

Comment: @Havenard Thanks for the advice. I needed big-engian to little-endian tho. Sorry for not delivering that information well. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) will convert a numeric value into a sequence of bytes, suitable for sending over the network. The sequence of bytes will be either little-endian or big-endian according to the [format string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment):

```
In [7]: addr=0x30313233

In [8]: struct.pack("@I", addr) # native
Out[8]: '3210'

In [9]: struct.pack("<I", addr) # little-endian
Out[9]: '3210'

In [10]: struct.pack(">I", addr) # big-endian
Out[10]: '0123'
```

But note that in the ordinary course of network programming, you'll never use the above formats. Instead, you'll always send in "network byte order":

```
In [11]: struct.pack("!I", addr) # network byte order
Out[11]: '0123'
```